# How does std::vector allocate objects?

Tags: c++, vector, std, allocator

How does `std::vector` allocate objects? It would seem as if it just uses `std::allocator::allocate` to create a block of memory, but then never calls `std::allocate::construct`. Is this true? Does `std::vector` only allocate memory and never construct the objects as memory allocation?

What if there is no default constructor? How is the constructor called when there is no default constructor on the object? What if there is more than one parameter?

For example, with this code there is no default constructor and std::allocator allows it.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A{
protected:
    int m;
public:
    explicit A(int a) : m(a) { }
};

int main(){
    vector<A> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Prætorian: Could you please provide the source for this? The code I just put on the question shows that it will compile in VS2010, and I believe it also compiles in gcc.

Comment: It's quoted from the C++11 standard

Comment: @Prætorian: Is this a new C++11 rule or was it in C++03?

Comment: @Prætorian: Could you provide the source for where you found that? I can't seem to locate that. Also the code above compiles fine and was just an example.

Comment: @chadb: The source is the standard for programming language C++, as released in 2011. However, he is wrong on one account: `std::vector` itself does not *require* that `T` be default constructable. Not in C++11 or C++03. **However**, calling `vector`'s constuctor that takes a size, without providing the second parameter (the object to copy into the array), *does* require that it be default constructable. In C++03, this is because it will default construct the other argument. In C++11, it is because it will default-construct the elements in-place.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yep, I was reading it wrong. That requirement only applies to the vector constructor that takes a size argument

Comment: @Prætorian: If you're going to give him a link to C++11, you could at least use the [real specification](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). This is much closer to the published spec, with only minor editorial differences.

Comment: @NicolBolas I found the one I posted on Wikipedia's [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) page; it even claims it's the most recent freely available working draft!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has rather changed since C++11.

In C++03, `construct` could only perform copy-construction in-place.

However, note that `std::vector` in particular is an array of objects, but there is a distinct size and capacity. That is, there can be more *empty* elements beyond the end of the part of the array that contains useful data.

That is why the standard library's allocator has a separation between "construction" and "memory allocation." The `allocator` does do both, but *not at the same time*. This allows `std::vector` to allocate more memory than it uses. When you add new elements, it doesn't necessarily have to allocate more memory; it can just use the spare memory it has left over via a call to `allocator::construct`.

Also, note that all of the C++03 functions that add elements to `std::vector` *take an element* as a parameter. `push_back`, `insert`, even the [sized constructor takes as a value as an argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). Yes, it's a default parameter, but it still takes a value as an element. This element is *copied* into the vector, using a call to the allocator's `construct` method which takes a copy.

In C++11, standard containers are required to use the `allocator_traits<>::construct` function. This is a varadic function that forwards its parameters to the actual construct. This traits function will (by default. It can be specialized) call the `allocator::construct` method if that call is well-formed. If it isn't, it will try placement `new`.

This allows for the new `emplace` functions to work.

But yes, the objects contained in standard library containers are in fact constructed objects. Even if the allocator's `construct` method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

It's implementation dependent, but a typical implementation uses `std::allocator::allocate` to allocate the block of memory, and then uses the placement new to construct, via the copy constructor (or move constructor in C++11), the instances.

When elements are erased, their destructors are directly invoked to destroy the objects, even if the underlying memory isn't released.

Comment: Copy and move constructors have nothing to do with placement new.

Comment: What if there is no default constructor? How is the constructor called when there is no default constructor on the object? What if there is more than one parameter?

Comment: @Nicol: I was refering to the fact that the `std::vector` tends to use the copy (or move) constructors of the class in question during it's construction operators.  Since placement new still invokes a constructor (just like non-placement new), that was my intent

Comment: ... and what if that parameter is an object of the same type. Hello, it's time for the copy constructor.